# openlitespeed rewrite rules conversion from apache

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, rewrite-rules, apache, nginx

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# behind proxy
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} ^http$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# plain
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} ^http$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# wordpress in subfolder subf
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subf/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subf/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subf/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END Wordpress
```

Had the previous rewrite rules in apache working without any problem. Moved to Openlitespeed. I saw there is a conversion to be made

https://open.litespeedtech.com/kb/apache-rewrite-rules-in-openlitespeed/

And so tried to modify the rewriterules like the following, but I don't get the syntax right. I'd like wordpress to be in subfolder subf and when visitor go to mysite.com the website will show wordpress installation in folder mysite.com/subf

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# behind proxy
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} ^http$
RewriteRule /.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# plain
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} ^http$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule /.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# wordpress in subfolder subf
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subf/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/.*)$ /subf/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^//)?$ subf/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END Wordpress
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution...thanks to a friend (DM you know who you are!) !!!

The solution is to replace the last line with:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /it/index.php [L]
```